Cannot find namespace 'CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls' in WinUI 3 project with .NET 8
enter image description here
I'm developing an application using WinUI 3 with .NET Core 8 and have installed CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls, but I'm encountering errors when trying to use SettingsCard in XAML. Here are the error messages I'm receiving:
Error (active) CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'CommunityToolkit.WinUI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
Error XLS0429: Undefined namespace. The 'using' URI refers to a namespace 'CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls' that could not be found.
Error XLS0414: The type 'controls:SettingsCard' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

I have added the following lines to my XAML file:
xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"
xmlns:ui="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI"

And my XAML code looks like this:
<Page
    x:Class="Easy_Minecraft_Gui_WinUI3.SettingsPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Easy_Minecraft_Gui_WinUI3"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"
    xmlns:ui="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Transparent">
    
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Spacing="4">
            <controls:SettingsCard x:Name="settingsCard"
                                   Description="This is a default card, with the Header, HeaderIcon, Description and Content set."
                                   Header="This is the Header"
                                   HeaderIcon="{ui:FontIcon Glyph=&#xE799;}"
                                   IsEnabled="{x:Bind IsCardEnabled, Mode=OneWay}">
                <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBoxItem>Option 1</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Option 2</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem>Option 3</ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox>
            </controls:SettingsCard>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>

I have checked the references and settings, but I'm still unable to resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, and is there any way to fix it?
Thank you!

What I Tried:

Installation of CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls: I have installed the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls package via NuGet in my project.

XAML Namespace Declarations: I added the appropriate namespace declarations in my XAML file to reference the controls from the toolkit:
xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"
xmlns:ui="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI"


Rebuilding the Project: After adding the references, I rebuilt the project multiple times to ensure all dependencies were correctly resolved.

Cleaning Solution: I cleaned the solution and then rebuilt it to eliminate any caching issues that could cause the error.

Checking for Updates: I ensured that both Visual Studio and the Community Toolkit were updated to their latest versions.



Are you by chance using central package management? If so, you would need to add the community toolkit nuget package reference in the Directory.Packages.props file

I don't see CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls package. Are you sure that's what it's called? I installed CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls.Primitives and CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Extensions.

I had the same problem today. You need to make sure that your target framework matches. At the time of writing there is only one version of this package and it needs:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>


This worked, thanks!
